# Large image blurs on feed dialog

Tags: android, facebook, image, image-quality

I am using a URL of an image which is 160x368 in dimension. The URL I am getting is from a web-service and is used at many places in my and some other applications too, so I can't change it.
I am passing this URL to the parameter of feed dialog as follow:

```
params.putString("picture", getFbImageUrl());
facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params,new customDialogListener());
```

The image on feed dialog is displayed with very poor quality and is not looking very good. However on the actual wall post it just gets shrinked and looking fine.
I just want to show a good quality of (even a small version of ) the same image on the feed dialog, which looks nice too.
Any help?

Comment: You can hit the url first, get the image, resize it than place in Dilagoue, its quality will be improved.

Comment: The dialog takes an image URL as a parameter, not an image. So this won't work too :(

Comment: getFBImageURl() is a built in method, or you have write this on your own ?

Comment: This is my own method which returns the URL of the image which I need to put there. The method takes only the URL as the argument.

Comment: see the below Ans i put below, i took help from Graph API, its working fine in WebView, i hope it will work. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally worked around this by changing the web-service to give me a already compressed image link, to use in the facebook sharing.
The another solution was to use photo-sharing, but since it's not what I(read client) wanted, so I chose the first option.
If anyone has any better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Append this line "/picture?type=small" at the end of the url, as i done here,

```
params.putString("picture", getFbImageUrl());
facebook.dialog(this, "feed", params,new customDialogListener());

private String getFbImageUrl()
{   URL url;
return url+"/picture?type=small"
}
```

I hope this will work, as per refrence https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: The trick works for getting the profile picture of a user, but I want to share the picture. I haven't checked if it works in my problem or not, will let you know once I am able to check it again.